# If $A \cap B = B \cap C$, then prove that $P(B \setminus A) = P(B \setminus C)$

Tags: probability

So as the title says:

> If we know that $A \cap B = B \cap C$, then prove: $P(B \setminus A) = P(B \setminus C)$ ($P$ stands for probability)

I really don't know where to start but it should be something easy and short. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: First prove that for every $x \in B$ we have $x \in A \iff x \in C$.  Then prove that $B \setminus A = B \setminus C$.

Comment: ok, so when i prove that B\A = B\C, does it mean then that i'm done. in other words is this true: B\A = B\C ⟺ P(B\A)=P(B\C)

Comment: Yes to the first question, because $X = Y \implies f(X) = f(Y)$ for _any_ sets $X$ and $Y$ and _any_ function $f$.  No to the second question (the converse is not valid.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $B\setminus A = B\setminus (A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, $B \cap A = B \cap C$ means that $x \in B$ implies $x \in A \iff x \in C$, however, this is equivalent to $x \in B$ implies $x \notin A \iff x \notin C$, that is, $B \cap A^c = B\cap C^c$, and your result follows.

If you would like a more formal derivation:
\begin{align}
%
B \cap A &= B \cap C \\
(B \cap A)^c &= (B \cap C)^c \\
B^c \cup A^c &= B^c \cup C^c \\
%
B \cap (B^c \cup A^c) &= B \cap (B^c \cup C^c)\\
%
B \cap A^c &= B \cap C^c
\end{align}

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the most complex side, I would calculate using simplification as follows: for any sets $\;A,B,C\;$ we have

\begin{align}
& P(B \setminus A) = P(B \setminus C) \\
\Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"Leibniz' rule -- the best we can do without knowing anything about $\;P\;$"} \\
& B \setminus A = B \setminus C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \setminus A \;\equiv\; x \in B \setminus C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \land x \not\in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \land x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \in B\;$ out of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; (x \not\in A \;\equiv\; x \not\in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; (x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: bring $\;x\in B\;$ back into the $\;\equiv\;$ again -- suggested our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \land x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \land x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"introduce $\;\cap\;$ by its definition; set extensionality"} \\
& B \cap A = B \cap C \\
\end{align}

This completes the proof.